# How to create a dataframe from dictionary with details of stocks

Tags: python, python-3.6, pandas-datareader

I need to create a dataframe with closing prices of the stocks of the companies that I have given in the list.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime(2017,1,1)
end = datetime(2017,1,12)    
f = web.DataReader(['BP','CVX'], 'iex',start,end)
```

f in the code is returning a dictionary as shown below.
How can I get the closing price of the stocks of listed companies in a DataFrame.

{'BP':               open     high    low  close   volume
 date
 2017-01-03  38.100  38.1218  37.79  38.00  8779164
 2017-01-04  38.045  38.3400  37.94  38.29  6883266
 2017-01-05  38.140  38.6800  38.14  38.57  6505685
 2017-01-06  38.160  38.1900  37.85  37.91  5800932
 2017-01-09  37.580  37.6500  37.31  37.31  5533626
 2017-01-10  37.250  37.4500  37.11  37.11  3922015
 2017-01-11  37.200  37.6550  37.06  37.55  4422586
 2017-01-12  37.990  38.0000  37.66  37.76  4698473,
 'CVX':               open    high     low   close   volume
 date
 2017-01-03  118.38  119.00  116.59  117.85  7404774
 2017-01-04  118.41  118.65  117.60  117.82  6679943
 2017-01-05  118.00  118.48  116.72  117.31  5928637
 2017-01-06  117.45  117.58  116.38  116.84  4762474
 2017-01-09  116.29  116.36  115.11  115.84  6891790

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `axis=1` for concatenate along columns and select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) second level of `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = pd.concat(f, axis=1).xs('close', axis=1, level=1)
print (df)
               BP     CVX
date                     
2017-01-03  38.00  117.85
2017-01-04  38.29  117.82
2017-01-05  38.57  117.31
2017-01-06  37.91  116.84
2017-01-09  37.31  115.84
2017-01-10  37.11     NaN
2017-01-11  37.55     NaN
2017-01-12  37.76     NaN
```

Or  concatenate along indices, but get `MultiIndex` in indices:

```
df = pd.concat(f)['close']
print (df)
     date      
BP   2017-01-03     38.00
     2017-01-04     38.29
     2017-01-05     38.57
     2017-01-06     37.91
     2017-01-09     37.31
     2017-01-10     37.11
     2017-01-11     37.55
     2017-01-12     37.76
CVX  2017-01-03    117.85
     2017-01-04    117.82
     2017-01-05    117.31
     2017-01-06    116.84
     2017-01-09    115.84
Name: close, dtype: float64
```